# AngularjJS directive scope function execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have following example and i want to execute the content of the scope function before returning it but it doesnt

```
directives.directive('itemElement', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : function(scope) {
            var itemModelVar = getValue(scope.item.testdata, field.caption);
            console.log('test');// this is not executed at all  for example
            return {
                item : '=item',
                field : '=field',
                schematypes : '=schematypes',
                itemmodel : itemModelVar
            };
        },
        templateUrl : 'partials/templates/item-simple.html'

    };
});
```

This leads to itemModelVar  being undefined.

Comment: I thought stackoverflow was free of haters. You are so resilient, man!

Comment: Can you explain why you'd like to do this?  `scope` usually isn't used to do this.  Check out `controller` if you want to add a function with logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS directive definition does not allow this kind of scope definition. Scope within directives can be assigned in 3 ways.

- `scope: false`
- `scope: true`
- `scope: {}`

In the first scenario, the scope within the directive is the same as the parent scope.
In the second scenario, the parent scope is prototypically inherited in the directive scope.
In the third scenario, the scope is defined is known as isolate scope since here the scope is not inherited but a new identifier which is specific to the directive. Isolate scopes are used for reusable components.

Try and understand the behavior of scope in angularjs.

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: thanks again. i always used http://docs.angularjs.org/ and although its good, there are not many technical details.